# What SIM card size does the Nexus 7 use?

Tags: nexus-7, sim-card

The iPad uses silly little SIM cards that pretty much need to be purchased ad-hoc. This means that in a pinch situation you can't e.g. swap SIM cards between your tablet and your phone (e.g., if either's ran out of credit).

What size does the Nexus 7 use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Nexus 7 (with mobile data) takes a micro SIM card.

See this page from Google support on how you can [Insert & activate a SIM card](http://support.google.com/nexus/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=2802869).

Comment: @badp Most devices, including Android phones, are coming with a micro SIM these days (except some Apple products are using an even smaller nano-SIM). So you shouldn't be too much worried about it.

Comment: Also there are cheap Adapters to place a micro SIM card in a normal SIM card device. And you can easily cut a normal SIM card into the micro SIM format with a scissor. So it isn't really a problem after all.

Comment: @badp MicroSIM-to-MiniSIM adapters are readily available and cheap (example for $1 http://www.amazon.com/Micro-card-adapter-Mini-German-Made/dp/B003OG8G6W).  All sizes of SIM are functionally identical, given that all the actual circuitry is directly under the contacts.  All the extra size is simply empty plastic to make handling easier.

Comment: @Flow do u know of a good tutorial to show the cutting, or is it just generally cutting plastic as per Compro01 comments above ? ie the difference between a Sim and Micro Sim is simply additional plastic.